# Countifs formula using weekday function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this formula that I am using for conditional formatting that highlights cells based on the date in column `AG`. I got the formula from a stackoverflow genius :-)

**Logic:**

If `Today()` is a Monday I need to highlight the cell if the date in `AG` is the PREVIOUS Friday, Saturday and Sunday

If `Today()` is a Tuesday through Friday then I need to highlight if the date in `AG` is the previous day

The formula works great in the conditional formatting cells but I also would like to adapt it to a `COUNTIFS` formula so I can count the amount of records that meet the criteria.

Here is the formula: `=OR(AND(WEEKDAY(TODAY())>= 3,WEEKDAY(TODAY())<=6,INT(AG10)=INT(TODAY()-1)),AND(WEEKDAY(TODAY())=2,INT(AG10)>=INT(TODAY()-3),INT(AG10)<=INT(TODAY()-1)))`

Can someone help me tweak it to work with `COUNTIF` or `COUNTIFS`?

Comment: Are the values in column AG dates or are they datetimes (i.e. include a time as well as a date)? The reason for asking is that you might be able to get rid of all the INT's which would make life simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(((WEEKDAY(TODAY())>= 3)*(WEEKDAY(TODAY())<=6)*(INT(AG10:AG100)=INT(TODAY()-1)))+((WEEKDAY(TODAY())=2)*(INT(AG10:AG100)>=INT(TODAY()-3))*(INT(AG10:AG100)<=INT(TODAY()-1))))
```

If the Dates in AG do not have time component then we can use:

```
=IF(AND(WEEKDAY(TODAY())>= 3,WEEKDAY(TODAY())<=6),COUNTIF(AG:AG,TODAY()-1),IF(WEEKDAY(TODAY())=2,COUNTIFS(AG:AG,">=" & TODAY() -3,AG:AG,"<="&TODAY()-1),0))
```

Comment: Yes that's what I had in mind you could do with Countif's

Comment: @TomSharpe I was stumped on where you were going.  Then realized I did not need to include the Weekday in the COUNTIF at all, took me a moment, but then the light bulb went off.

Comment: Thinking about it a bit more, you can probably use countif even with a time component with a bit of adjustment.

Answer (score 1):

So just for completeness (with apologies to @Scott Craner for borrowing his formula) this should work even if the values are datetimes:

```
=IF(AND(WEEKDAY(TODAY())>= 3,WEEKDAY(TODAY())<=6),COUNTIFS(AG:AG,">="&TODAY()-1,AG:AG,"<"&TODAY()),IF(WEEKDAY(TODAY())=2,COUNTIFS(AG:AG,">=" & TODAY() -3,AG:AG,"<"&TODAY()),0))
```

because  Today()-1 is 3/1/19 00:00 and Today() is 4/1/19 00:00 so anything >= the first and < the second (e.g. 3/1/19 12:00) must be yesterday.